# Deploy only certain resources into Azure using DevOps Pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-rm-template, azure-monitoring, azure-bicep

I have a main.bicep template with multiple resources that I deploy to Azure via my DevOps pipeline. My template is currently configured to either deploy all modules to Azure or none. However, I would like to customize this in my pipeline so that only certain resources show up in my resource group so that it acts like a selection catalog.

However, I need advice and help on how to solve the problem as I can’t find the right approach. Attached you can see a snippet from my bicep template below.

– main.bicep–

```
param deployAppInsights bool = true
param deployNetworkWatcher bool = true
param deploySentinel bool = true
```

Example for a module

```
// Deploy App Insights resource

module appInsights 'AzureMonitor/AppInsights/appInsights-temp.bicep' = if(deployAppInsights) {
  name: 'appInsightsDeployment'
  params: {
    appName: appInsightsName
    regionId: regionId
    // tagsArray: tagsArray
    requestSource: requestSource
    workspaceResourceId: workspace.outputs.resourceWorkspaceIdOutput
  }
}
```

This snippet is in my pipeline - yml

(I would like to shorten the parameters block by using override parameters.)

```
parameters:
  - name: appInsights
    type: boolean
    default: True
    values: 
    - True
    - False

inputs:
   overrideParameters: -deployAppInsights false -deployNetworkWatcher true -deploySentinel true
```

Currently, my override parameters are hardcoded, but I’d like to keep it in a general way, like for example:

```
overrideParameters: -deployAppInsights ${{appInsights}} -deployNetworkWatcher ${{networkWatcher}} -deploySentinel  ${{sentinel}}`
```

However, this does not unfortunately work. Could anyone please help me in this regard, how I can solve this or how the variables need to look like?

Thank you very much!

Best regards
Jennifer

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, the syntax you are using is wrong in the below code

```
overrideParameters: -deployAppInsights ${{appInsights}} -deployNetworkWatcher ${{networkWatcher}} -deploySentinel  ${{sentinel}}
```

Since you have already defined **parameters** section in the Yml file. The correct syntax is

```
overrideParameters: -deployAppInsights ${{parameters.appInsights}} -deployNetworkWatcher ${{parameters.networkWatcher}} -deploySentinel  ${{parameters.sentinel}}
```

A sample code snippet for your reference

```
parameters:
  - name: var1
    type: string
  - name: var2
    type: string
  - name: bool1
    type: bool
```

...
omitted
...

```
      - task: AzureResourceManagerTemplateDeployment@3
        inputs:
          deploymentScope: 'Resource Group'
          azureResourceManagerConnection: ''
          subscriptionId: ''
          action: 'Create Or Update Resource Group'
          resourceGroupName: rg-${{parameters.var1}}-${{parameters.var2}}
          location: ''
          templateLocation: 'Linked artifact'
          csmFile: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/arm.json
          csmParametersFile: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/arm.parameters.json
          deploymentMode: 'Incremental'
          overrideParameters:
            -string1 ${{parameters.var1}}
            -string2 ${{parameters.var2}}
            -flag ${{parameters.bool1}}
```

For more, please refer to the link from Microsoft. [Azure Devops Template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/templates?view=azure-devops)

Edit: After the first comment
Please update your 'appInsights' parameter as follows

```
parameters:
  - name: appInsights
    type: boolean
    default: true
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! If I now try your approach, unfortunately I receive this error message: 'A value for the 'appInsights' parameter must be provided.' (same for the other two resources). How can I solve this problem? Thank you for your help!

Comment: please refer to the last Edit section of the answer. That should probably solve your problem. For more info refer to this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/templates?view=azure-devops

Comment: Something is still not working and I don't understand why. In my main template, I have declared my parameter with the type bool (deployAppInsights bool = true). In my pipeline I have also set the type of the parameters of type boolean and even changed the name to yesNo (as referred from the provided link you have sent). But I keep on getting this message which I really don't understand why: ##[error]Deployment template validation failed: 'Template parameter 'deployAppInsights' was provided an invalid value. Expected a value of type 'Boolean', but received a value of type 'String'.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve "##[error]Deployment template validation failed: Expected a value of type 'Boolean', but received a value of type 'String'"

From what I understand, Azure DevOps will always pass a string, regardless of the parameter type used in the pipeline. I used the ARM template function "bool()" to convert the string. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/template-functions-logical#bool

(Note: Incomplete code snippets just to illustrate)

1. In the Pipeline YAML, use a bool parameter and pass it to the ARM deployment. I'm using AzureResourceManagerTemplateDeployment@3.

```yaml
  parameters:
  - name: excludeFromLatest
    displayName: "Exclude Image from latest"
    type: boolean
    default: false

  - task: AzureResourceManagerTemplateDeployment@3
    displayName: "Deploy Image Builder Template"
    inputs:
      ...
      overrideParameters: -excludeFromLatest ${{ parameters.excludeFromLatest }}
```

2. In the ARM template and parameter file, define the parameter as a string.

```json
    "parameters": {
        "excludeFromLatest": { 
            "type": "string"
            }
```

3. Define an ARM template variable, converting the string to a bool. Use the variable instead of the parameter to pass a bool to the template.

```json
    "variables": {
        "excludeFromLatest": "[bool(parameters('excludeFromLatest'))]"
        }
        
        
    "distribute": [
        {
           "type": "SharedImage",
           "excludeFromLatest": "[variables('excludeFromLatest')]",
        }
     ]
```

4. If using Bicep, the equivalent to step 2 and 3 would be something like this:

```json
param excludeFromLatest string = 'false'

var excludeFromLatest_var = bool(excludeFromLatest)

    distribute: [
      {
        type: 'SharedImage'
        excludeFromLatest: excludeFromLatest_var
      }
    ]
```